# Illegal string offset Warning nav-menu.php

Tags: php

I am receiving this error

> "Warning: 
>   Illegal string offset 'output_key' in /home/smsti/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 601

and I realized this section of code in the file is wrong, however I'm not that great in PHP yet and I am wondering if someone can help me re-write this section to eliminate the error.

```
$items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++;
```

Comment: can you share your `$items`array here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this below lines in your wp-config.php instead of

### old code

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

### new code

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```